# Javascript promise chain hell

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a problem with promise chains that I don't know how to resolve. Summary of my code: I do a mongoose query for a specific user, fetch his CarIds and then query each car for his details and return these details via JSON response.

```
let carsDetails = [];

  User.findById(userId)
    .then(user => {
      const carIds = user.carsDetails;
      carIds.forEach((carId) => {
        Car.findById(carId)
          .then(car => {
            console.log(car);
            carsDetails.push(car);     
          })
          .catch(err => { throw err; });
        });

      return res.status(200).json({ data: carsDetails });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
```

The problem is that no cars get actually pushed onto carsDetails array on the `carsDetails.push(car);` line, because it jumps to return statement before it manages to fill up the array. Is there a workaround that could do those queries and return a result in a form of an array, object...? I tried writing everything in `async await` form too with self-made async forEach statement, but it doesn't help me. Any suggestions? I already tried with `Promise.all()`, but didn't manage to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: `I tried writing everything in async await form too with self-made async forEach statement` you should show what you have tried there, because `await`/`async` is the way to go, with `await`/`async` you use refular `for ... of` loops  instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Promise.all, if it dint work then you might not have used it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have a lot of cars to find, you may want to do your query in a single request, no need to stack multiple promises :

```
User.findById(userId)
  .then(user => {
    const carIds = user.carsDetails; 
    // if carsDetails is not an array of objectIds do this instead :
    // const carIds = user.carsDetails.map(id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
    return Car.find({ _id: { $in: carIds });
  })
  .then(userCars => {
    res.status(200).json({ data: userCars })
  })
```

Comment: `Car.find({ _id: { $in: carIds })` is most certainly better than using `map` with `Promise.all`, as is it most likely is handled as one query by the DB.

Comment: This was the most optimal solution of them all. I shaw that I used Promise.all the wrong way, but the $in selector really does job the best. Thanks!

Comment: A `.catch` handler would just make it better.

Comment: @ambianBeing Of course, I just want to point out that writing `.catch(error => { throw error; });` is the same as not writing anything

Comment: @Dyo Not writing anything would not be the same, because of `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` in case promise gets rejected. Although I get the point.

Comment: @ambianBeing `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is thrown if the error was not cought at any point, but you can still handle these errors at a higher scope, throwing an error in a catch block will still create an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Comment: A `.catch(error => { throw error; });` is definitily useless because it does not do anything except rethrowing the error. It would be better to write `.then(userCars => {res.status(200).json({ data: userCars })}).catch(next)` assuming it is `express` and the third agrument `next` of the middelware is used. @ambianBeing

Comment: @Dyo Yeah! That why not wrting anything would do that. throw the errors all one wants at `catch` handler as long as they are caught/handled at the caller. I didn't say to throw the error instead **handle the error**. Yeah right! crux of a comment +1 @t.niese

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to collect the promises of your `Car.findById(carId)` calls and use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them before responding. You can use `array.map()` to map each ID to a promise from `Car.findById()`.

```
User.findById(userId)
  .then(user => {
    const carIds = user.carsDetails;
    const carPromises = carIds.map(carId => Car.findById(carId))
    return Promise.all(carPromises)
  })
  .then(cars => {
    res.status(200).json({ data: cars })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    throw error
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

`await`/`async` is the way to go, with `await`/`async` you use regular `for ... of` loops instead of `forEach`.

```js
  async function getCarDetails() {
    let carsDetails = [];

    let user = await User.findById(userId);

    const carIds = user.carsDetails;

    for (let carID of carIds) {
      let car = await Car.findById(carId)

      console.log(car);

      carsDetails.push(car);
    }

    return res.status(200).json({
      data: carsDetails
    });

  }
```

Or you use `Promise.all` and `map` instead of `for ... of`

```
  async function getCarDetails() {
    let user = await User.findById(userId);
    const carIds = user.carsDetails;

    let carsDetails = await Promise.all(carIds.map(carID => Car.findById(carID)));

    return res.status(200).json({
      data: carsDetails
    });
  }
```

Those two solutions are slightly different. The second version with the map will send all requests to the DB at once, and then waits until they are all resolved. The first one will send the request one after another. Which one is better depends on the use-case, the second one could lead to request peeks, and might be easier be abused for DDoS.

Comment: Please explain why the second approach is better

Comment: @AvcS it is not necessarily better, it is different. The second will send all requests to the db at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async/await to solve this problem. It will be more readable and clean

```
async function getCarDetail() {
  let carsDetails = []

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId)
    const carIds = user.carsDetails

    for (let i = 0; i < carIds.length; i++) {
      const carId = carIds[i]

      const car = await Car.findById(carId)
      carsDetails.push(car)
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ data: carsDetails })

  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the same definitions of "readable" and "clean", nesting try/catch blocks looks very bad to me